# Java, math (adding, dividing, multiplying) all together

Tags: java, android

This is my code and it whines about calc 2 and the result.

```
BigDecimal costNum1 = new BigDecimal(number3.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal costNum2 = new BigDecimal(number1.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal costNum3 = new BigDecimal(number2.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal calc1    = costNum1.multiply(costNum2);
        BigDecimal calc2    = calc1.divide("100");
        BigDecimal calc3    = calc2.multiply(costNum3);
        result.setText(calc3).toString());
```

Safe to say I'm quite new in this, I'm almost there but I can't make up what is wrong. It's for my first Android App.

Answer (score 4):

[BigDecimal#divide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) accepts another BigDecimal, not a String.

Try

```
calc2.divide(new BigDecimal("100"));
```

Also, you have one too many parentheses in your last line.

Try

```
result.setText(calc3.toString());
```

You should always count the number of left parens, and see if it matches the number of right parens. If you use an IDE like eclipse, it should point these problems out to you automatically.